# How would I test window prompts and confirms with Karma / Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, tdd, karma-jasmine, e2e-testing

I'm pretty new to TDD and I've been doing some programming prompts from reddit to learn it. This one is an acronym generator that asks for a string to be converted, displays it, and then asks if the user wants to generate another.

My trouble is that I don't know how to write the tests to fill in the prompt and then hit the ok button. Then select the ok or cancel button when asked again.

```
(function(ns, undefined)
{
    ns.generateAcronym = function()
    {
        var s = window.prompt("Enter the words to be converted into an acronym.");
        var matches = s.match(/\b(\w)/g);
        var acronym = matches.join("").toUpperCase();
        if(window.confirm("Your acronym is: "+acronym+". Would you like to generate another?"))
        {
            ns.generateAcronym();
        }

    };

})(window.pprompts = window.pprompts || {});


pprompts.generateAcronym();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright - I think I figured this out. If anyone has better methods, I'd love to see/read them :)

I realize I could have put all of this into one `it` block, but I like seeing the `Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS` over `Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS`.

```
describe('Acronym Generator', function() {

    beforeEach(function()
    {
        spyOn(window, "prompt").and.returnValue("Java Script Object Notation");
        spyOn(window, "confirm");
        pprompts.generateAcronym();
    });


    it('should generate a window prompt', function() {
        expect(window.prompt).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Enter the words to be converted into an acronym.");
    });

    it('should generate a confirm dialog with the proper acronym', function() {
        expect(window.confirm).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Your acronym is: JSON. Would you like to generate another?");
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this is still the best/proper way to handle the dialogs.  It'd be even better if you decoupled the `expect`s from the exact verbiage by just using `toHaveBeenCalled()`, and then added a different section of tests that are dedicated to the acronym generation, but that's probably a little pedantic for this.